# Laravel 6.6 and elasticsearch Call to undefined method

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver to play ball with the Laravel 6.6

I'm upgrading older installation, however installed the new packages, set it up per instructions, cleared caches and checked that Model has needed

```
use ScoutElastic\Searchable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MyModel;
```

and

```
use Searchable;
```

However, what I am getting with: MyModel::search('*')->...

is:

```
Call to undefined method App\MyModel::search()
```

Also if I run:

```
php artisan elastic:update-mapping "App\MyModel"
```

I get:

```
class must extend Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MyModel and use the ScoutElastic\Searchable trait.
```

I'm surely making some simple idiotic mistake somewhere in the configuration but missing what?

Edit: Model (model's name is of course always the same, just calling it MyModel here. All worked perfectly in previous Laravel version)

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MyModel;
use ScoutElastic\Searchable;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class MyModel extends Model
{
    use Searchable;



protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
protected $table = 'MyModel';

protected $fillable = [
    'type',
    'name',
    'description',
];
protected $indexConfigurator = MyModelIndexConfigurator::class;

protected $searchRules = [
    //
];

protected $mapping = [ 




 // my mappings here

 ]
    ];
```

Comment: Can you post the full source of the model class?

Comment: @mdexp sure thing! Added.

Comment: Shouldn't you refer to `App\MyModel` class instead of `App\Model` to use the `search` method and issue the `update-mapping` command from artisan?

Comment: @mdexp just a typo while I changed to different model name. That's all correct in the code.

Comment: Is `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MyModel;` as well a typo? Shouldn't be `Model` instead of `MyModel`? Could you also post the stacktrace of the error you get with the artisan console command?

Comment: It's typo, yes. Actually I worked around this by simply creating a new model and then using it (this model was in use in older laravel version which I am updating from), I have absolutely no idea yet why it does work and this one doesn't since I even copy pasted the model's contents into the new one and everything runs fine (using the same IndexConfigurator too)

Comment: It's nice to hear that you solved your problem. Maybe add that solution as an answer so other people with the same issue as yours could also try it!

Comment: It's not the solution actually :). It's just a workaround, I'm still looking for the actual cause since it should work. When I do I will add it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is experiencing this some day. I recreated the model to work around the problem, I have no idea why the old one did not work as everything is identical. Didn't investigate it further than that but if you have similiar issues, recreate your model and you should be good to go.